# How to update multiple row at a time

Tags: php, mysqli, escaping

I have below code , I want to update multi row at  a time but not working.
Could any one help me ?
it is show Uninitialized string offset , what is wrong with me ?
I have below code , I want to update multi row at  a time but not working.
Could any one help me ?
it is show Uninitialized string offset , what is wrong with me ?

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
$con->set_charset("utf8");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  };

$sql="SELECT * FROM test";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
// Count table rows
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

// Check if button name "Submit" is active, do this
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{

$count=count($_POST["id"]);
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['id'][$i]);
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name'][$i]);
$lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['lastname'][$i]);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email'][$i]);

$sql1="UPDATE test SET name='$name[$i]', lastname='$lastname[$i]', email='$email[$i]' WHERE id='$id[$i]' ";
$result1=mysqli_query($con,$sql1);
}
}


?>
<table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<tr>
<td>
<table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td align="center"><strong>Id</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Name</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Lastname</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Email</strong></td>
</tr>
<?php
$ss="SELECT * FROM test";
$rr=mysqli_query($con,$ss);

while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($rr)){
?>
<tr>
<td align="center">
<input name="id[]" type="hidden" id="id" value="<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>">
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="name[]" type="text" id="name" value="<?php echo $rows['name']; ?>">
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="lastname[]" type="text" id="lastname" value="<?php echo $rows['lastname']; ?>">
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="email[]" type="text" id="email" value="<?php echo $rows['email']; ?>">
</td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
<tr>
<td colspan="4" align="center"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
```

So what can i do ?

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Uninitialized string offset:

Answer (score 0):

You named your input fields "id[]", "name[]", "lastname[]", "email[]", but then your trying to get them from the post vars using 'id', 'name', 'lastname', 'email'.

Html forms use the name attribute on input elements to name post variables. So you have to access the post values using "id[]", "name[]", "lastname[]", "email[]", unless you update your inputs to have different names.